# flatten tree to array and give index value manually

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a tree structure. I want to flatten it to array of objects. I'm able to flatten it but I want `newIndex` to increment for each object.

**It can have any number of elements and depth could be anything.**

**Feel free to suggest any other better way**

```js
const tree =[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 8,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 9,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(flatten(tree))

function flatten(tree, index = 10, flatArray = []) { 
    if (tree && tree.length > 0) {
      for (const tr of tree) {
        flatArray.push({ id: tr.id, newIndex: index++ });
        if (tr.children && tr.children.length > 0) {
          this.flatten(tr.children, index, flatArray);
        }
      }
    }
    return flatArray;
}
```

Output I'm looking for is:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "newIndex": 10
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "newIndex": 11
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "newIndex": 12
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "newIndex": 13
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "newIndex": 14
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "newIndex": 12    <------ it should be 15
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "newIndex": 13   <------- it should be 16
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object for keeping track of indice. This approach updates the object and because of the same object reference, the counter is updated along all function calls.

```js
function flatten(tree, index = { index: 10 }, flatArray = []) { 
    if (tree && tree.length > 0) {
        for (const tr of tree) {
            flatArray.push({ id: tr.id, newIndex: index.index++ });
            if (tr.children && tr.children.length > 0) {
                flatten(tr.children, index, flatArray);
            }
        }
    }
    return flatArray;
}

const tree = [{ id: 1, children: [] }, { id: 2, children: [{ id: 6, children: [] }, { id: 7, children: [{ id: 8, children: [] }] }] }, { id: 3, children: [{ id: 9, children: [] }] }];

console.log(flatten(tree))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A slightly shorter approach is to return just a single array without having another parameter for the own array.

```js
function flatten(tree, index = { index: 10 }) { 
    const flat = [];
    if (!tree?.length) return [];
    for (const { id, children } of tree) {
        flat.push(
            { id, newIndex: index.index++ },
            ...flatten(children, index)
        );
    }
    return flat;
}

const tree = [{ id: 1, children: [] }, { id: 2, children: [{ id: 6, children: [] }, { id: 7, children: [{ id: 8, children: [] }] }] }, { id: 3, children: [{ id: 9, children: [] }] }];

console.log(flatten(tree))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```